# Я хочу использовать activity которое я подгрузил с github

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я захотел попробовать одну библиотеку с разными видами activity [ссылка](https://github.com/DingMouRen/LayoutManagerGroup) и как я могу использовать `EchelonLayoutManager` в своем проекте.(зависимости и все такое и добавил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EchelonLayoutManager это не Activity а LayoutManager
его нужно использовать например так
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new EchelonLayoutManager (this));

this это контекст Activity или Fragment

recyclerview - это ваш RecyclerView